# Using microsoft VoTT to annotate and export images as tfrecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am annotating an image set to use in this github guide (https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2), but when it gives the example train commands, it expects one tfrecord file. However this is where the problem arises, because Microsoft Visual Object Tagging Tool (VoTT) exports a tfrecord file for each image individually.

I have tried converting a pascal voc style dataset into a tfrecord but I can never seem to get the code to work, so that is also a possible solution.

Comment: can you specify the question ? is that you want to have several images as tfrecord instead of a single image one ?

Comment: I think he/she means VoTT outputs a tfrecord for each image file he/she labelled using that tool, but he/she wants the data in a single tfrecord file to train a model.